# TSQL select from another table in the where

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

I'm looking for a more elegant (possibly faster) solution to my predicament.

I have the following query to produce a report on a call traffic table:

```
SELECT 'Tariff1' as [Tariff], Count([Number]) as [Number of calls]  ,sum(convert(bigint,[Seconds]))/60 as [Minutes], sum([CustomerCost]) as [Customer Cost], sum([WholesaleCost]) as [WholesaleCost]
  FROM [MarchCalls]
 where [AccNo] in (select [accno] from [Tariffs] where [Tariff] = 'Tariff1')

union

SELECT 'Tariff2' as [Tariff], Count([Number]) as [Number of calls]  ,sum(convert(bigint,[Seconds]))/60 as [Minutes], sum([CustomerCost]) as [Customer Cost], sum([WholesaleCost]) as [WholesaleCost]
  FROM [MarchCalls]
 where [AccNo] in (select [accno] from [Tariffs] where [Tariff] = 'Tariff2')

union
SELECT 'Tariff3' as [Tariff], Count([Number]) as [Number of calls]  ,sum(convert(bigint,[Seconds]))/60 as [Minutes], sum([CustomerCost]) as [Customer Cost], sum([WholesaleCost]) as [WholesaleCost]
  FROM [MarchCalls]
 where [AccNo] in (select [accno] from [Tariffs] where [Tariff] = 'Tariff3')

 union

SELECT 'Total' as [Tariff], Count([Number]) as [Number of calls]  ,sum(convert(bigint,[Seconds]))/60 as [Minutes], sum([CustomerCost]) as [Customer Cost], sum([WholesaleCost]) as [WholesaleCost]
  FROM [MarchCalls]
```

A couple of points:
Convert(bigint) is required due to the volume of records and the numbers therein
The returned recordset has to remain in this format
This data (and database) is strictly read only
SQL server 2012

This query takes longer towards the end of each month and I need to get the time down

Can anyone help me streamline this?

Comment: change union to union all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using an IN, can you join on the AccNo field:

```
SELECT 
    T.[Tariff], 
    Count([Number]) as [Number of calls] ,
    sum(convert(bigint, [Seconds]))/60 as [Minutes], 
    sum([CustomerCost]) as [Customer Cost], 
    sum([WholesaleCost]) as     [WholesaleCost]
FROM [MarchCalls] M
inner join [Tarrifs] T on M.AccNo=T.Accno and  [Tariff] in ('Tariff1','Tariff2', 'Tariff3')
group by [Tariff] with ROLLUP
```

Comment: Actually, you can reduce the first three down to one query, edited above

Comment: Don't forget to change your first column to T.[Tariff]

Comment: That's much quicker, and the ROLLUP solved the issue I had with totals in joins. Thanks guys